# What is the % operator in python for?

Tags: python

I've seen the % operator being used in some Python code related to strings, such as:

```
String = "Value: " % variable
```

What does that mean? How is it different from using:

```
String = "Value: " + variable
```

Comment: Your first code line is missing something:
s = "Value: %s"%variable

Comment: Well it was throwing an error, so that's why I asked ;)

Comment: Note also that % operator for strings will be deprecated in python 3.1 and removed some time afterwards.  So if you're going to learn something new, it may be worth learning the new way :-) http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/

Comment: Note also that Value: %s would work regardless of variable's type. + variable will fail if variable is not a string, or doesn't support addition to strings.

Comment: Note, % hasn't been deprecated in Python 3.1 and, at this point, it seems unlikely it can ever go away in Python 3.  That said, the PEP 3101 string format method is certainly worth learning and using.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

its for inserting values into strings containing [format specifications](http://www.python.org/doc/2.4/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

```
string = "number is %d" % 1
```

or

```
string = "float is %.3f" % 3.1425
```

this works in a similar way as spintf in C

You can insert multiple values in two ways:

```
string = "number %d and float %f" % (1,3.1415)
string = "number %(mynum)d and float %(myfloat)f" % {'mynum':1,'myfloat':3.1415}
```

Comment: Reference: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations

Answer (score 2):

The % is the *string formatting operator* (also known as the *interpolation operator*), see http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 2):

For strings % is the [formatting operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations).  It also marks the start of the format specifier.

The + operator will concat a string at the end of the string with the right hand side of the +.   The % operator will replace the format specifier in a formatted way at the location of the format specifier.

For numbers % is the [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) or remainder after division.

Answer (score 0):

Read [formatting strings](http://diveintopython.net/native_data_types/formatting_strings.html)

- '%' is the formatting string operator
- '+' would be the concat operator

Answer (score 0):

According to John E. Grayson in his book "Python and Tkinter Programming", using string formatter rather than concatenation could increase the performance for at least 25 percent.

a = x + ' ' + y + ' ' + z

is 25 percent slower than

a = '%s %s %s' % (x, y, z)

In Python 3, you could also do like this:

a = '{} {} {}'.format(x, y, z)

Answer (score 0):

(As an aside, in case you didn't know): When not being used on strings, `%` acts as a modulo function

```
>>> 5 % 5
0
>>> 1 % 4
1
```